# Finding secondary calendars

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps

We're changing G-Suite domains and I'm trying to find all secondary calendars so that I can eventually get them all updated to use our new domain in the ID. For some reason, Google makes this process a nightmare scenarios for admins without any convenient solution.

I got GAM setup and found some powershell script on here that gets me 95% of the way there, but I need a small tweak.

```
if (!($env:Path -like '*Google Apps Manager*'))
{
$env:Path += ";C:\GAM\gam.exe"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Adding Google Apps Manager to Path 
environment variable"
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Checking to see if we're connected"
gam info domain

$list = gam.exe print users

foreach ($entry in $list)
{
  if ($entry -eq "Email")
  {
      continue
  }

  $summary = gam.exe user $entry show calendars 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "Summary:"
  if ($summary)
  {
       Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $entry
       $summary
  }
}
```

This returns each user and the summary, which is a short-hand name for each calendar, but I need the full-name of each calendar so I can transfer them over.

Every full-name is on a string beginning with "Calendar:" and each name ends in "@group.calendar.google.com"

You can tell I have no experience in code. I wish I could directly ask the person who posted this, but don't have the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `"Summary:"` with `"Calendar:"` in this line:

```
  $summary = gam.exe user $entry show calendars 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "Summary:"
```

So after the change, the line should be:

```
  $summary = gam.exe user $entry show calendars 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "Calendar:"
```

And then you will get the calendar address (or full-name as you called it) instead of the summary.

Explanation:
The `gam.exe user $entry show calendars` command outputs a long multi-line text with information about the user calendars, and the following `Select-String` command filters only the lines that contain the text we choose.
Therefore, we changed the "Summary:" to "Calendar:"